# SQL group searching and matching between two tables

Tags: sql-server, join

Working on a physical security migration. Have two tables. First table (AreaAccess) lists the badgeholder with the areaid's the badgeholder has access to. Second table (AreaGroups) has areaid's grouped together in sets. The goal is to read the cardholder's AreaAccess records and then search the AreaGroups for the count of the best or exact match of the cardholder's areas to a group.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Also use formatted text rather than images.

Answer (score 0):

Curious why you didn't give this a shot first. If you aren't as familiar with SQL, here's a great link to get started: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Also, it's extremely helpful if you can provide a sample of what you want the outcome to look like. It doesn't have to be fancy, just a few rows/columns that can demonstrate what you're hoping to see.

Here's a possible look. However, your question is a little vague, so this is a best guess.

```
create table ##CardToArea --Is this table a log, or is it grouping of permission? I'm treating it as a log, but the wording of your question isn't quite clear.
    (
    CardholderID int not null
    , AreaID int not null
    );

insert into ##CardToArea
    (CardholderID,AreaID)
values
    (1961,11)
    ,(1961,25)
    ,(1961,28)
    ,(1961,71)
    ,(1961,73)
    ,(1961,74)
    ,(1961,44)
    ,(1961,50)
    ,(1961,51)
    ,(1961,52);


create table ##AreaToGroup
    (
    AreaID int not null
    , AreaGroupID int not null
    , unique (AreaID,AreaGroupID)
    );

insert into ##AreaToGroup
    (AreaID,AreaGroupID)
values
    (33,0)
    ,(45,0)
    ,(45,7)
    ,(19,16)
    ,(17,16)
    ,(11,16)
    ,(11,48)
    ,(17,48)
    ,(17,49)
    ,(15,49)
    ,(11,49);

select
    isnull(convert(nvarchar,atg.AreaGroupID),'Not defined') as [AreaGroupID]
    , cta.CardholderID
    , count(*) as [CountOfAccesses]
from ##CardToArea as cta
    left join ##AreaToGroup as atg on cta.AreaID = atg.AreaID
group by
    atg.AreaGroupID
    , cta.CardholderID;

drop table ##AreaToGroup;
drop table ##CardToArea;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Robert - thanks for the response.
This is my query I had worked through yesterday. Looking only at two sample users (23006 and 28190). The result is a full report of the areasets these users are part of. What I have been trying to do, hence yesterdays question, is to limit the query to the top five areacounts for each cardholder. Attempted to use ROW_NUMBER processing but that was not working primarily because of the alias for "count(g.areaid)" in the select. I also tried numerous sub queries but to no avail.

```
select  g.AreaGroupID, ag.caption, count(g.areaid) as AreaCount, a.CardholderID
from AHBadgeActivity B
join areaaccess a on a.CardholderID=b.CardholderID
left join AreaGroupSet g
on         g.areaid=a.AreaID
left join AreaGroup ag on AG.AreaGroupID=g.AreaGroupID
where (a.CardholderID=23006 or a.CardholderID=28190) and DeleteFlag=0 and g.AreaGroupID <> 0
group by g.AreaGroupID, ag.Caption, a.CardholderID
order by a.cardholderid, AreaCount desc
```

Here is the sample output. My goal is to limit to the top five AreaCounts for each Cardholder.

[Output from Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNWAe.png)